# Umbraco rendering content using razor from api service that inherits UmbracoApiController

Tags: api, razor, umbraco

I have an umbraco api controller that I created that inherits the UmbracoApiController class and returns a list of items.  I also have another umbraco site that is to call that api url using razor and to render the content onto the page.  I was trying the following:

```
dynamic xmlv = new DynamicXml(umbraco.library.GetXmlDocumentByUrl("http://myapiurl.com"));
```

But it is telling me that it is not well formed since it does not have any xml node in the first line.

I am wondering if there is a way to either make the api add an xml node to the beginning of the api web service such as the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>
```

or if there is another way I can get the contents of my api url in order to render the results onto my page in razor.

Both of the sites are running on Umbraco version 7.2.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution for this.  I used a WebClient on my razor partial view page to call the api url and then I deserialized the contents into the exact model that it was sent over as.  I was then able to use the deserialized object to loop through all news items and display them on the page.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
@using System.Net;
@using System.Text;
@using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
@using myapplicaiton.Models;
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage
@{
var contents = "";
using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
{
      webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
      contents = webClient.DownloadString(apiurl);
}
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var newsItemsApiViewModel = serializer.Deserialize<NewsItemsApiViewModel>(contents);
}
```

I then render my partial view on my template view using the following:

```
@Html.Partial("News")
```